# Solving for conjugate of a long complex function

Tags: complex

I have the following function of ω

```
f[ω_] := (2 Sqrt[Γ] (4*g2^2 + (κ1 - 2*I*ω) (κ2 - 2*I*ω)))/(4*g2^2 (Γ - 
2*I*ω) + (4*
 g1^2 + (Γ - 2*I*ω) (κ1 - 
2*I*ω)) (κ2 - 2*I*ω))
```

And I wish to obtain the poles for the denominator of the function:

```
wroots1 = x /. Solve[(Denominator[f[ω]] /. {ω -> x}) == 0, x]
```

The result is of the following:

```
{-(1/6) I (Γ + κ1 + κ2) + (I (-16 (\
Γ + κ1 + κ2)^2 + 
   48 (4 g1^2 + 
      4 g2^2 + Γ κ1 + Γ...}
```

Basically a really long ugly solution. My goal is to obtain the conjugate of wroots1, however, when I do it straightforwardly:

```
wroots2 = 
Simplify[Conjugate[wroots1], 
Assumptions -> {Γ ∈ 
  Reals, κ1 ∈ Reals, κ2 ∈ Reals, 
 g1 ∈ Reals, 
 g2 ∈ Reals, ω ∈ Reals, 
 4 (-16 (Γ + κ1 + κ2)^2 + 
      48 (4 g1^2 + 
         4 g2^2 + Γ κ1 + (Γ + \
κ1) κ2))^3 + 
   4096 (-36 g1^2 (Γ + κ1 - 
         2 κ2) + (2 Γ - κ1 - \
κ2) (36 g2^2 + (Γ + κ1 - 
            2 κ2) (Γ - 
            2 κ1 + κ2)))^2 > 0}];
```

I am returned with:

```
{1/48 I (8 (Γ + κ1 + κ2) + 
8 2^(1/3) (-12 g1^2 - 
   12 g2^2 + (Γ + κ1 + κ2)^2 - 
   3 (κ1 κ2 + Γ (κ1 + \
κ2))) Conjugate[
  1/(-36 g1^2 Γ + 72 g2^2 Γ + 
     2 Γ^3 - 36 g1^2 κ1 - 
     36 g2^2 κ1 - 3 Γ^2 κ1 - 
     3 Γ κ1^2 + 2 κ1^3 + 
     72 g1^2 κ2 - 36 g2^2 κ2 - 
     3 Γ^2 κ2 + 
     12 Γ κ1 κ2 - 
     3 κ1^2 κ2 - 3 Γ κ2^2 - 
     3 κ1 κ2^2 + 2 κ2^3...}
```

Clearly, Conjugate refuses to take the conjugate of said function. I tried doing

```
wroots2 = wroots1 /. {I -> -I}
```

But that doesn't work as well. I'm at lost at what to do here and I could use any help I can get. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can get the Conjugate by `wroots1 /. Complex[a_, b_] -> Complex[a, -b] `, but I'm not clear, what you realy want.

Answer (score 1):

If you `Conjugate` the equation before `Solve`, you'll get the complex-conjugated solutions (complex analysis is nice!):

```
wroots1 = w /. Solve[Denominator[f[w]] == 0, w];
wroots1C = w /. Solve[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Denominator[f[w]]]] == 0, w];
```

This way you don't have to complex-conjugate the solutions. The downside is that the order of the solutions in wroots1 and wroots1C may not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ComplexExpand`, but the cube root term (what I define as `cRoot` below) interferes with its logic.
The following could be a work-around (suppressing all output):

`wroots2 =`
`FullSimplify[Conjugate[wroots1], 
Assumptions -> {Γ ∈ 
  Reals, κ1 ∈ Reals, κ2 ∈ Reals, 
 g1 ∈ Reals, 
 g2 ∈ Reals, ω ∈ Reals, 
 4 (-16 (Γ + κ1 + κ2)^2 + 
      48 (4 g1^2 + 
         4 g2^2 + Γ κ1 + (Γ + \
κ1) κ2))^3 + 
   4096 (-36 g1^2 (Γ + κ1 - 
         2 κ2) + (2 Γ - κ1 - \
κ2) (36 g2^2 + (Γ + κ1 - 
            2 κ2) (Γ - 
            2 κ1 + κ2)))^2 > 0}];`

`wroots2 = wroots2 /. (-36 g1^2 (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Kappa]1 - 
        2 \[Kappa]2) + (2 \[CapitalGamma] - \[Kappa]1 - \[Kappa]2) \
(36 g2^2 + (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Kappa]1 - 
           2 \[Kappa]2) (\[CapitalGamma] - 
           2 \[Kappa]1 + \[Kappa]2)) + 
     1/64 \[Sqrt](4 (-16 (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Kappa]1 + \[Kappa]2)^2 \
+ 48 (4 g1^2 + 
               4 g2^2 + \[CapitalGamma] \[Kappa]1 + (\[CapitalGamma] \
+ \[Kappa]1) \[Kappa]2))^3 + 
         4096 (-36 g1^2 (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Kappa]1 - 
               2 \[Kappa]2) + (2 \[CapitalGamma] - \[Kappa]1 - \
\[Kappa]2) (36 g2^2 + (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Kappa]1 - 
                  2 \[Kappa]2) (\[CapitalGamma] - 
                  2 \[Kappa]1 + \[Kappa]2)))^2))^(1/3) -> cRoot`

`wroots2 = wroots2 /. 
  1/(-36 g1^2 (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Kappa]1 - 
         2 \[Kappa]2) + (2 \[CapitalGamma] - \[Kappa]1 - \[Kappa]2) \
(36 g2^2 + (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Kappa]1 - 
            2 \[Kappa]2) (\[CapitalGamma] - 
            2 \[Kappa]1 + \[Kappa]2)) + 
      1/64 \[Sqrt](4 (-16 (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Kappa]1 + \[Kappa]2)^2 \
+ 48 (4 g1^2 + 
                4 g2^2 + \[CapitalGamma] \[Kappa]1 + (\[CapitalGamma] \
+ \[Kappa]1) \[Kappa]2))^3 + 
          4096 (-36 g1^2 (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Kappa]1 - 
                2 \[Kappa]2) + (2 \[CapitalGamma] - \[Kappa]1 - \
\[Kappa]2) (36 g2^2 + (\[CapitalGamma] + \[Kappa]1 - 
                   2 \[Kappa]2) (\[CapitalGamma] - 
                   2 \[Kappa]1 + \[Kappa]2)))^2))^(1/3) -> (1/cRoot)`

`ComplexExpand[wroots2]`

You can then substitute the expression for `cRoot` back into the answer.